# Examine the behaviour of the derivative if the function tends to zero as x tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and f is differentiable everywhere.
Prove or disprove the following statement:
If  $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$$then $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false, $f'$ may have no limit.
Consider $f(x)=\frac 1 x \cos(x^2)$ on $[1,\infty)$ and prolongate it differentiably by another differentiable function on $(-\infty,1)$.

Then $f'(x)=-\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x^2}-2\sin(x^2)$ on $(1,\infty)$ which has no limit at $\infty$.

Comment: Nice counterexample.